# How to make controller read object from post body (The requested resource does not support http method 'POST)

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, post, asp.net-web-api

Am try to using post ajax get the data from controller without changing url (by insert value in the post body)
with the code below  but it appear that server respond me with 
"The requested resource does not support http method `'POST`"

how to make a controller read a body from post object

Controller Class***

```
 public AllAppType Post(int limit) 
 {         
     using (var ms = new MySampleServiceClient(Wcf.Routing.RouterBindings.Local, 
                         Wcf.Routing.RouterAddresses.Local.RequestReply))
     {            
          if (limit == 1)
          {
               var objectToSerialize = new AllAppType();
               objectToSerialize.Band = new List<Banditem> 
               {
                     new Banditem { Id= 1, Name = "Potato", Detail = "ปากดี" },
                     new Banditem { Id= 2, Name = "Body Slam", Detail = "ขอบฟ้า" },                  
                     new Banditem { Id= 3, Name = "Kala", Detail = "ไปเป็นแฟนกันตั้งแต่เมื่อไ              
                     new Banditem { Id= 4, Name = "Bigass", Detail = "ดีแต่ปาก"},
                     new Banditem { Id= 5, Name = "Paradox", Detail = "ฤดูร้อน"},

               };        
               return objectToSerialize;
           } 
           else if (limit == 2)
           {
                var objectToSerialize = new AllAppType();
                objectToSerialize.Band = new List<Banditem> 
                {                         
                      new Banditem { Id= 6, Name = "Test1", Detail = "111" },
                      new Banditem { Id= 7, Name = "Test2", Detail = "222" },
                      new Banditem { Id= 8, Name = "Test3", Detail = "333"},
                      new Banditem { Id= 9, Name = "Test4", Detail = "444"},
                      new Banditem { Id= 10, Name = "Test5", Detail = "555"},

                };
            return objectToSerialize;

          }

          else
          {

                var objectToSerialize = new AllAppType();
                objectToSerialize.Band = new List<Banditem> 
                {   
                     new Banditem { Id= 11, Name = "Cnblue", Detail = "CCC" },
                     new Banditem { Id= 12, Name = "Ft island", Detail = "FFF" },
                     new Banditem { Id= 13, Name = "Girl generation", Detail = "GGG"},
                     new Banditem { Id= 14, Name = "Miss-A", Detail = "AAA"},
                     new Banditem { Id= 15, Name = "SNSD", Detail = "SSS"}
                };

                return objectToSerialize;

           }

     }
}
```

html***

```
   function runpost1() {
            $('#postresult').text("");
            answer.clearAttributes;
            $.ajax({
                url: "All",
                type: "post",
                content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: {limit :1 },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (answer) {

                    $.each(answer.Band, function (key, item) {
                        //      Add a list item for the product.
                        $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#postresult'));

                    });

                    // $("#answer").text(JSON.stringify(answer));
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You need a method to post to `public ActionResult MyMethod(int limit) { // build your collection return Json(objectToSerialize); }` and then in the ajax function call it using `url: '@Url.Action("MyMethod", "yourControllerName")',` - and remove `content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thankyou sir but it saying that cannont implicity convert type System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult to SampleApp.Allcontrolelr.Actionresult how should i fix it

Comment: I am assuming you must have some incorrect using statements in your controller - you need `System.Web.Mvc` (or is this an `ApiController`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke
yes, it is Apicontroller

Comment: Then you need to property tag your question! Change the method to `public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult MyMethod(int limit)`